# ERROR: " Cannot resolve symbol '@string/edit_message' " Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to follow the android tutorial on: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html
But when I reach the part where you have to add a button my Android Studio keeps returning this errors:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '@string/edit_message'
Cannot resolve symbol '@string/button_send'
```

XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I can't find the right solution on other stackoverflow questions and I'm pretty sure i used the right code on the android tutorial from google.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Strings

Comment: For some reason they have you do this part before adding to the strings.xml in the tutorial... I just got hung up on the exact same thing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must define those 2 strings in strings.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      ...
        <string name="edit_message">something text /string>
        <string name="button_send">something text</string>
      ...
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 5):

Update your strings.xml located under res/values/

with

```
<string name="edit_message">Edit</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

- In Android Studio, from the res/values directory, open strings.xml.
- Add a line for a string named "edit_message" with the value, "Enter a message".
- Add a line for a string named "button_send" with the value, "Send".

[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)